# What permissions should I grant an IAM so that it may create instances and manage them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to create an IAM user that is allowed to create new instances and fully manage them (including terminate them), but has no access to any other instances. I tried the following (the iam user name is `auto-provision`):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource":"*"
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":["ec2:*"],
            "Resource":"*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Owner": "auto-provision"
                }
            }
        }

  ]
}
```

This doesn't work as expected. The user can create an instance fine, but has no access to manage it. I assume my `Condition` in the last statement doesn't work because an "owner" is the entire account and not the user?

Comment: The ec2:owner key refers to the account-id, not the user who created the instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#policy-syntax

Comment: @AssafLavie Thanks for verifying that. Do you have any suggestions as to what I could use instead?

Comment: Not presently, I'm afraid. My first thought was CFN stacks, but that just boils down to restricting access based on tags... will give it more thought.

Comment: I am in control of the images being used, so I suppose I could create a tag before creating the AMI and then restrict on tags? Although I'm not sure if the tag would follow the AMI?

Comment: I don't think they will. I believe what happens technically is that you run the instances, and then attach tags to them, not even in the same api operation. Hack: you could probably differentiate by some other attribute. e.g. create a subnet per user, then restrict by subnet.

Comment: Looks like I could create a profile, associate that with a role and then attach the role to my user. The profile can be assigned on launch, it would seem. I'm going to test this and post back here.

Comment: OK, no luck with that approach.

Comment: So, I tried using a placement-group and change the condition to `ec2:PlacementGroup` and it works, except some functions can not be controlled on an instance level (for example management of tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around for this, with some suggestions from Assaf Lavie in the comments.

First I created a placement-group called `auto-provision-placement-group`. Then I changed my policy file to something like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource":"*"
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":["ec2:*"],
            "Resource":"*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:PlacementGroup": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:111111111111:placement-group/auto-provision-placement-group"
                }
            }
        }

  ]
}
```

When launching new instances, I assign the relevant placement group. E.g. (using Ruby fog):

```
fog.compute.servers.create(:placement_group => 'auto-provision-placement-group', ...)
```

The servers are created into the placement group, which is then used to control access to most functions. I deliberately allowed full access to tags, since I use it to identify ownership of machines. The placement-group then becomes my "access control".

A hack, but it works.